# JS Image Slider with specific text to each image

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've followed a tutorial about JS image sliders. I'm trying to have a text box display on each image (figured that out) but I need the text to be specific for each image. The images being grabbed from an img folder and are in order (image-0, image-1, etc). I'm guessing I'll need some array but I can't figure out how to do this in JS and have the corresponding text display on each correct image. Code provided. Any help?

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="images">

  <div id="btns">
    <button type="button" class="btn prevBtn">&#8617;</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn nextBtn">&#8618;</button>
  </div>
  
  <div id="textBlock">
      <h4>This is the image</h4>
  </div>

</div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS

```
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".nextBtn");
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prevBtn");
const container = document.querySelector(".images");

let counter = 0;

nextBtn.addEventListener("click",nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener("click",prevSlide);


function nextSlide () {
  container.animate([{opacity:"0.1"},{opacity:"1.0"}],{duration:1000,fill:"forwards"});
  if(counter === 4){
    counter = -1;
  }
  counter++;
  container.style.backgroundImage = `url(img/image-${counter}.jpg`
}

function prevSlide () {
  container.animate([{opacity:"0.1"},{opacity:"1.0"}],{duration:1000,fill:"forwards"});
  if(counter === 0){
    counter = 5;
  }
  counter--;
  container.style.backgroundImage = `url(img/image-${counter}.jpg`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you counter is indexed *0* and goes up to  all you need is an array:

```
const descriptions = [
  "A nice walk in the park",    // for the image counter 0
  "My dog and me",              // for the image counter 1
  // etc.
];
```

than all you need to do is:

```
textBlock.textContent = descriptions[counter];
```

**But...**

I don't know where you found that *toturial* but it's a really a great example on how not to build a gallery. The animation is odd, it's overly simplistic and cannot account for multiple galleries. It's repetitive and unmodular. And the total number of slides should never be hardcoded, that's why we use a programming language after all. And yes, it can count the number of items using `.length`.
Code should be reusable:

```js
class Gallery {
  constructor(id, slides) {
  
    this.slides  = slides || [];
    this.total   = this.slides.length;
    this.curr    = 0;
    this.EL      = document.querySelector(id);
    this.EL_area = this.EL.querySelector(".Gallery-area");
    this.EL_prev = this.EL.querySelector(".Gallery-prev");
    this.EL_next = this.EL.querySelector(".Gallery-next");
    this.EL_desc = this.EL.querySelector(".Gallery-desc");
    
    const NewEL = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
    
    // Preload images
    this.ELs_items = this.slides.reduce((DF, item) => (DF.push(NewEL("img", item)), DF), []);
    this.EL_area.append(...this.ELs_items);

    // Events
    this.EL_prev.addEventListener("click", () => this.prev());
    this.EL_next.addEventListener("click", () => this.next());
    
    // Init
    this.anim();
  }

  // Methods:

  anim() {
    this.curr = this.curr < 0 ? this.total - 1 : this.curr >= this.total ? 0 : this.curr;
    this.ELs_items.forEach((EL, i) => EL.classList.toggle("is-active", i === this.curr));
    this.EL_desc.textContent = this.slides[this.curr].alt;
  }

  prev() {
    this.curr -= 1;
    this.anim();
  }

  next() {
    this.curr += 1;
    this.anim();
  }
}


// Use like:
new Gallery("#gallery-one", [
  {alt: "My fluffy dog and me", src: "https://picsum.photos/400/300"},
  {alt: "Here, we seem happy!", src: "https://picsum.photos/300/300"},
  {alt: "We are making pizza?", src: "https://picsum.photos/600/300"},
]);
```

```css
.Gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.Gallery-area > * {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.Gallery-area > *.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.Gallery-btns {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.Gallery-desc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="Gallery" id="gallery-one">
  <div class="Gallery-area"></div>
  <div class="Gallery-btns">
    <button type="button" class="btn Gallery-prev">&larr;</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn Gallery-next">&rarr;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="Gallery-desc"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I've been looking at this and trying to understand how it works exactly, and I'm making progress.  I actually got that code from the CodeAddict youtube channel :(. Self-taught here so it's been rough trying to comprehend what I'm looking at. Thank you again for the help!